# Чем плох COPY в psql и как можно его заменить?

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql

Имеется запрос(PostrgreSQL 9.5) вида:

`'COPY(SELECT * FROM table) TO STDOUT WITH CSV HEADER'`.

Справляется отлично и импортит красиво в таблицу все данные.
Появилось мнение, что данная операция является не оптимизированной за счёт `COPY`. Каких-либо аргументов почему я не услышал. Отсюда вытекает, что требуется сделать точно такой же запрос, но без `COPY`,

т.е. вида `'SELECT FROM * table TO STDOUT WITH CSV HEADER'`, но это не работает.

Comment: "_Появилось мнение, что данная операция является не оптимизированной_". Не надо полагаться на какие либо мнения без доказательств. А ваш ответ если даже copy "не оптимизарована" ничем не помогает, так как в той прямо статье написано, что `\copy` является оболочкой для copy, т.е. использует ее же. И да, с внешними файлами ничего кроме самой copy работать не может, потому как сам SQL ничего не знает о внешних файлах и знать не должен

Comment: Такой человек, у которого есть только мнение и отрицание документации и книг. Проблема в том, что я нахожусь в его подчинении. Всё приходиться проверять. Я сослался на статью, если кому-то интересны подробности про COPY, пласт текста переписывать не хотел.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Именно `COPY TO STDOUT` и весьма не случайно использует штатная утилита `pg_dump` для получения данных. А ведь для операции снятия дампа время работы является весьма важной характеристикой. Сама команда `COPY` и отдельный сетевой протокол для него специально были спроектированы для эффективной передачи массива данных потоком:

- как в направлении импорта в базу новых данных - разница по сравнению даже с prepared insert и commit пачками всё равно может быть значительной и именно `COPY` рекомендуется [официально в документации](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/populate.html#POPULATE-COPY-FROM)

> Note that loading a large number of rows using COPY is almost always faster than using INSERT, even if PREPARE is used and multiple insertions are batched into a single transaction.

- так и в направлении экспорта данных из базы. Даже есть не рассматривать `COPY` в локальный файл напрямую силами `PostgreSQL` (что вовсе исключает нагрузку на сеть), `copy to stdout` имеет все шансы оставаться наиболее производительным вариантом. Как уже упомянул, для реализации `COPY` используется во многом другой код, начиная с [отличающегося сетевого протокола](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/protocol-flow.html#PROTOCOL-COPY), намеренно спроектированного для передачи больших объёмов данных.

> The COPY command allows high-speed bulk data transfer to or from the server.

---

Но если оппонент не читает документацию, то с чего ему слушать кого-то неизвестного в интернете, пусть даже опытного `PostgreSQL DBA` и автора вот уже нескольких патчей?

Замерьте на своей задаче и покажите результаты сравнения.

Comment: Ух, вот это крутой ответ) У меня нет скрипта и доступа к машине, где это будет использоваться в данный момент, и вряд ли снова получу. Думаю, я вам поверю.

Answer (score 0):

Ответ нашёлся. 
Команду `COPY` можно слегка улучшить заменив на `\copy`(под капотом всё равно идёт вызов COPY), но целиком убрать нельзя. Обе команды позволяют задать формат для выгрузки данных (text, csv, binary), что `SELECT` не позволяет.
Подробнее об особенностях каждой из команд в [статье](https://tyvik.ru/posts/postgresql-psql/).